# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo (android eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to get the input value from EditText in SearchUser to query in SearchResult

Here is my Code for SearchUser :

```
package com.example.yearbookmuict9sec2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class SearchUser extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_user);



    addButtonListenerHomeButton();
    addButtonListenerViewAll();
    addButtonListenerSearchButton();
}

private void addButtonListenerSearchButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText edtSearch;
            String Answer;
            edtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
            Answer = edtSearch.getText().toString();

            Intent goAnswer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchResult.class);
            goAnswer.putExtra("Answer", Answer);
            startActivity(goAnswer);


        }
    });
}
private void addButtonListenerViewAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewALLBUTTON);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(SearchUser.this,ViewAll.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void addButtonListenerHomeButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.HomeButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(SearchUser.this,Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_user, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is my activity_search_user :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView4"
    android:background="#fffbf8f0"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:text="Back Home" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/viewALLBUTTON"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:background="#ffff6c41"
    android:text="View All"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_180" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:background="#ff606efd"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewALLBUTTON"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Here is my code for SearchResult :

```
package com.example.yearbookmuict9sec2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchResult extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase mDb;
Database mHelper;
Cursor mCursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);


EditText txtAnswer;
Button btnBack;
String showAnswer;
txtAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
showAnswer = getIntent().getStringExtra("Answer");

txtAnswer.setText(showAnswer);



    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    mHelper = new Database(this);
    mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mHelper.onUpgrade(mDb, 1, 1);    
    mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + Database.COL_StudentID + ", " 
            + Database.COL_FNAME + ", " + Database.COL_LNAME+ ", " 
            + Database.COL_NNAME + " FROM " + Database.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE " 
            + Database.COL_StudentID + " = ?", new String[] {showAnswer});

    ArrayList<String> dirArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while ( !mCursor.isAfterLast() ){
        dirArray.add("ID : " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COL_StudentID)) + "\n" 
                + "Firstname : " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COL_FNAME)) + "\n"
                + "Lastname : " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COL_LNAME)) + "\n"
                + "Nickname : " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COL_NNAME)));
        mCursor.moveToNext();   
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDir = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext() 
            , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dirArray);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapterDir);

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
    datum.put("First Line", "First line of text");
    datum.put("Second Line","Second line of text");
    data.add(datum);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
            new String[] {"First Line", "Second Line" }, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHelper.close();
    mDb.close();  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_result, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is my activity_search_result :

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/backToHome"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#ffafff9b"
    android:text="Back to Home" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Student"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my LogCat :

```
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961): Process: com.example.yearbookmuict9sec2, PID: 4961
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yearbookmuict9sec2/com.example.yearbookmuict9sec2.SearchResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at com.example.yearbookmuict9sec2.SearchResult.onCreate(SearchResult.java:39)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
12-09 03:57:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4961):     ... 11 more
```

Help me please. 
What i have to do to fix this problem? I'm new here.

Comment: what is the line (SearchResult.java:39) . You are getting NULL there

Comment: may one of your element remain un-initialized check for it

Answer (score 0):

txtAnswer is null.  This is because it is not in the activity's view.  Your activity loads its view as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
```

Yet the element with ID answer id not defined in activity_search_result.xml.  It is defined in activity_search_user.xml.

So your problem is either:

- a) You are loading the wrong view for your activity OR
- b) You forgot to add the EditText with ID answer to your view (activity_search_result.xml)

Edit - looking at your code, I think it is likely that option is is the problem.  So to fix this, change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_user);
```

Comment: @Winz Lin - Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sourced on line `39` in `SearchResult.java`. You can see this in the LogCat on the line after the one that starts with `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

`txtAnswer` is not a valid id for an `EditText` object in your `activity_search_result.xml`, so it returned `null` on line `35` when you searched for it. You cannot call `.setText()` on a `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

You `activity_search_result.xml` does not contain any view that you have specified in your activity. You may have to pass right layout xml file in `setContentView` or change `id` of `EditText` and `Button`.